# Tuscany shower faucet single lever turned to hot, water stops coming out of shower head

Tags: shower

When the faucet is turned up to hot water max position, the pipes vibrate and the water stops coming from the shower head.  I have adjusted the red plastic knob for the maximum position and even tried without the red knob and still the same.  There is a green knob behind the red one but I am unsure if he is suppose to be adjusted or how to remove.  I have turned up my hot water heater and all other faucets are receiving plenty of very hot water.

Answer (score 1):

The hot water inlet side of your valve may be clogged with rust or mineral deposits.  I have had that happen before.  In my case there was a galvanized steel pipe section screwed directly into a copper pipe section, which always causes rust in the pipe (galvanic corrosion).

Based on having the red and green adjustments, this sounds like a single-handled valve with a cartridge in the center.  You will need to remove the valve cartridge to clean out any deposits.

Is this a newly-installed valve in the shower, or is it an existing valve that just recently started having problems?

Comment: This is a new faucet that was installed during a remodel about 5 years ago.  No problems til now...yes it is a single handled valve.  I just bought a new one and installed and still have the problem.

Comment: Hmm, that's frustrating. What kind of pipes are they between the water heater and this valve? Any chance there is a mix of steel (galvanized) and copper?

Comment: original pipes copper and some pex used.